# How to store result of regionprops as a a matrix using for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, image-processing, centroid

```
for i=1:length(blocks)
    for j=1:length(blocks)
        temp = blocks{i,j};
        s = regionprops(temp, 'Centroid');
        centroids= cat(1,s.Centroid);  
    end
end
```

When I display "centroids" outside these for loops it only shows the last iteration values, how can I make centroids maintain all iterations results by appending them one by one.

**Example:**

**itration-1:** 4, 2

**itration-2:** 6, 4

**itration-3:** 1, 3.2

**itration-4:** 2, 2.5

So that the

```
centroids = 
[4 2;
6 4;
1 3.2;
2 2.5];
```

But what I get as a result is Only the last iteration values 2,2.5; How can I keep all the values from all iterations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate `centroids` to the end of an array as follows:

```
centroids_arr = []; %Initialize centroids array to empty array.

for i=1:length(blocks)
    for j=1:length(blocks)
        temp = blocks{i,j};
        s = regionprops(temp, 'Centroid');
        centroids= cat(1,s.Centroid);  

        %Concatenate last value of centroids to the end of centroids_arr array (insert as new row to the bottom). 
        centroids_arr = [centroids_arr; centroids];
    end
end
```